# Service 'odoo' failed to build from docker

Tags: docker, odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to install odoo from docker.I have included odoo database backup module from odoo community apps. It requires pysftp python package.I am getting error as `ERROR: Service 'odoo' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install pysftp' returned a non-zero code: 1`

docker-compose.yml,

```
version: '2'
services:
  database:
    image: postgres:9.5
    container_name: database
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
    ports:
     - "5432:5432"

  odoo:
    image: odoo_zd:8
    container_name: odoov8
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    links:
      - database
    depends_on:
      - database

    environment:
      - PGHOST=database
      - PGUSER=odoo
      - PGPASSWORD=odoo
```

This is the problem line in Dockerfile,

```
RUN pip install pysftp==0.2.8
```

Comment: Please post the complete `Dockerfile`. Have you tried building it manually?

Comment: yes I am trying to build it manually. dockerfile is too long this is my source https://github.com/odoo/docker/blob/b3d55d295954fed2c6101854f1b133340c05c767/8.0/Dockerfile

Comment: Strange considering https://github.com/odoo/docker does not mention pysftp at all.

Comment: I manually added that at the end of my file because i needed that package

Comment: If you added it at the end of the file the issue might be that the current user is `odoo` and not `root` anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved,pysftp package has lot of prerequisites,

`RUN apt-get  gcc libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev 
RUN pip install pysftp`